# WPF - Use a ControlTemplate resource within a Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

When creating a Style, is it possible to set the ControlTemplate property to a previously defined resource?  For example, if I had the following in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
...
</ControlTemplate>
```

And then later wanted to use it in a Style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="???"/>
</Style>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">    
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: The important part is that the template must be defined BEFORE the style. Otherwise it's _XamlParseException: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key YourTemplateKey_

Comment: @Agent_L or one can just use `DynamicResource`