# Windows Store app failed to create style BasedOn shared style

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, resourcedictionary, win-universal-app

I have a windows 8.1 app.

In Project.Shared there is ResourceDictionary `SharedResources.xaml` with base style,

```
<Style x:Key="CommonLayerListItemStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource UnselectBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

in Windows Phone app is `StyleResources.xaml` wiht style based on this

```
<Style x:Key="LayerListItemStyle"   
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonLayerListItemStyle}"
       TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />        
</Style>
```

same in Windows app `StyleResources.xaml`:

```
<Style x:Key="LayerListItemStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonLayerListItemStyle}"
       TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="42,0,0,0" />
</Style>
```

All styles are used in UserControl created in Shared project. 
I do this to override FontSize on diffrent platforms.

I merged all dictionaries in App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/SharedResources.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/StyleResources.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

But my app does not start with Unhandled exception 
`Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key CommonLayerListItemStyle [Line: 10 Position: 37]`

Why does this happens?

Comment: Please see the comment below the accepted answer of [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652420/wpf-use-a-controltemplate-resource-within-a-style

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  You need to merge the SharedResources.xaml directly into StyleResources.xaml, and only reference StyleResources.xaml from App.xaml.

Here is a complete example:
http://blog.craftingbytes.com/2015/05/resource-sharing-in-windows-universal.html